# Not able to boot after upgrading to 12.10 in Sony laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, landscape

I am using Windows 7 Home basic and Ubuntu 12.04 on my SONY laptop, Ubuntu is default boot OS, today upgraded to 12.10, after this not able to boot latest version of Ubuntu and previous versions also. After installation, it asked me to restart, after rebooting it is showing only black screen. Windows is working fine.

Using recovery mode option entered into console mode  and try entered into GUI by pressing Alt+Function 7 , this it asking me to run landscape-config. Even after running the landscape-config the is no use. Can any one help me in this.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? What error message do you get or what problem are you having?

Comment: After selecting Ubuntu at grub menu, it is showing purple screen for few minutes, after that black screen it is displaying. Using recovery mode option entered into command line, here I am able to logging in. After that I pressed Alt+F7 keys to enter into GUI mode, then it is asking me to run landscape-config. Even after running the command there is no use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) We're sorry, but Ubuntu 12.10 is an end-of life product and is not supported any more, so it's off-topic here too.  Please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades on how to upgrade.